# How to validate Non-JSON response body using Karate

Tags: api, cucumber, karate

I am trying to validate an error response body of non-json format. I have tried using the schema as well as a keyword using contains to match. It is not working for me.

Actual Response response returned from API when multiple matches are observed in a post call:

```
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'NewEmp' for key 'employee_name_unique'}}
```

My Karate Feature:

```
Given url 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create'
def errResp = "error"  
And request {"name":"Hello1","salary":"123","age":"23"}
When method POST
Then status 200
Then match $ contains error #not working
Then match $ contains errResp #not working
```

Tried * match actual[0] == '#(^partSchema)' too from https://gist.github.com/ptrthomas/2a1e30bcb4d782279019b3d5c10b3ed1 . Not working

Comment: What are `error` and `errResp` refering to here?

Comment: error is the keyword I am trying to search for, errResp is the variable I have assigned 'error' to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please understand type-conversions first: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

Then convert the response to a string before you want to do *string* contains checks:

```
* string temp = response
* match temp contains 'error'
```

Comment: Please refer to my new comment under the question